# How do I make each Row in a Datatable refer to an item in a Visual List C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am working on a script for a project in a 3d surrounding and I have an Issue. Right now I have a Datatable consisting of several Columns with an unkown number of rows.

Script:

```
DataTable gldt = new DataTable();


public void UpdatefromTable(Visual sender)
{       
    gldt.Clear();
    gldt.Columns.Clear();
    gldt.Columns.Add("Group"); 
    gldt.Columns.Add("Type (short description)");
    gldt.Columns.Add("Number");
    gldt.Columns.Add("Name");
    gldt.Columns.Add("Bauteil");
    gldt.Columns.Add("Funktion");
    gldt.Columns.Add("Ort");   

    foreach (DataRow dr in ImportTable.Value.DataTable.Rows)
    {
        string name = dr["Name"].ToString();
        if (name.Contains(Maschinennummer.Value))
        {
            gldt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
        }
    }
}
```

This Data Table gets its Value from a bigger Table as you can see but that is not the issue. What I would like to do now is take each row in this table and make each row refer to one item in a visual list.

The Visual List is defined as follows

Script:

```
 [Auto]
CustomPropertyValue<VisualList> AllAdapters;


void OnCustomPropertyUpdated(StraightRollerConveyor sender, String name)
{

if (name == "Maschinennummer")
    {
        AllAdapters.Value.Clear();          

        foreach (var item in sender.Descendants)
        {
            if (item.Type == "Adapter")
            {
                AllAdapters.Value.Add(item);
            }

        }           
    }
}
```

Every row in gldt contains all the information about 1 specific "Adapter" in the Visual list and I would like to give that information to the items contained in that Visual List.

gldt and AllAdapters are defined Globally.

I hope I gave enough information to answer this question

Thanks in advance

Edit: Added the function in which the Visual List gets reset and filled. Not sure if this is important though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `ExtendedProperties` of the `DataTable` object for that purpose.

With this you can add objects to the datatable in a (key, value) relation.

As i understand it you refer an item to a whole row so you could use the row index as a key and the item object as value.

I.e.:

```
DataTable a = new DataTable();
a.ExtendedProperties.Add(1, "Hello");
a.ExtendedProperties.Add(2, "World");
var test = a.ExtendedProperties.Values;
foreach (string b in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}
```

You can add any object as a value, i simply used strings for tests.

EDIT:
Since i misread that you could do something simple as that:

```
foreach(DataRow row in gldt.Rows){
    var item = new Item();
    item.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
    item.Type = row["Type"].ToString();
    ...
    AllAdapters.Value.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I think we are talking past each other here. Maybe I did not explain it clearly. I want to give information from the Datatable to custom properties of the items in the visual list. EDIT: for example datarow 1 in my datatable contains a columns called name a column called position X and a column called type. I want to give this information to an object in my visual list. This item has three custom properties called Name, Position X and type. I want them to be set to the values in the first datatable row and after that I want the second row in my datatable to do thatto the next item in the list-

Comment: oh I'm srry i thought it the other way... then you simply need to loop through the datatable, read the cell values and add them to item before you add it to the list

Comment: But wouldn't I need to define the item first then? Also this will be used for components that contain 3 to 100 items of type "Adapter". Also this sounds like I would have to this by hand for every item in my list. Sorry I am very new to scripting. Thanks for the info though

Comment: you just need to do it for every _property_ that you want to add to the item. check out the edit i made to my post

Comment: Ah thank you. I think I understand how it works. I will try it and come back here later to post my progress.

Comment: If it helped or solved your problem you could upvote or [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Accepted it as an Answer, Thank you very much it helped a lot. I am using a different solution now though. I basically have an "AddAdapterFromCatalog", a "RemoveAdapterVisuals" and a "WriteDataToVisual" void now, which basically makes all of this a lot easier as I add all the information to the Visual while creating it. But as I said your answer helped A LOT!